# dynamic property names with spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring 4 PropertyPlaceHolder :

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/database.properties</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/app.properties</value>    
            <value>/WEB-INF/cdservice.properties</value>            
        </list>
    </property> 

</bean>
```

From the properties File I want to read properties in my application which I am reading thus:

```
@Service
public class FileUploadServiceImpl implements FileUploadService {

    @Value("${supporting.documents.location}")
    private String supportingDocumentsLocation;

    @Override
    public String removeFile(String xyz) {
       //Here I want to read property xyz which is dynamic
    }

}
```

As in above code I am able to read static properties using @Value annotation.
But how can I read a property like xyz which is dynamic.Please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Inject the Spring [*Environment*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) into your bean and you can read arbitrary properties:

```
@Service
public class FileUploadServiceImpl implements FileUploadService {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Value("${supporting.documents.location}")
    private String supportingDocumentsLocation;

    @Override
    public String removeFile(String xyz) {
        String value = environment.getProperty(xyz);
    }

}
```

Comment: It compiles but returns null

Comment: Then the property referred to by `xyz` isn't set. From the documentation for `Environment.getProperty(String key)`: "Return the property value associated with the given key, or null if the key cannot be resolved."